# How to Add If…Else Statements in JSX without having 2 if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I have two if statements written in ReactJS.

```
if (videoUrl !== undefined && videoUrl !== null && videoUrl.indexOf('youtube') !== -1) 
{
   videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
}
if (videoUrl !== undefined && videoUrl !== null && videoUrl.indexOf('vimeo') !== -1) 
{
   videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("https://vimeo.com/", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/")
}
```

I don't know how to make these `if else` statement, so it can check between youtube or Vimeo. Right now I can only use one if statement. If I leave both if statements on the place, one first if works.

Comment: your logic requires 2 if statements ... so, not sure why you think you can do this with one

Comment: Have you tried replacing `if` in your second statement with `else if`?

Comment: yes, your question wasn't explained very well, was it. You seem to say you don't want 2 if's ... didn't realise you wanted **more**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that many if, simply check for string

```js
let videoUrl = 'https://vimeo.com/';
if (typeof videoUrl === 'string') {

  if(videoUrl.indexOf('youtube') !== -1) {
     videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
   }
   if (videoUrl.indexOf('vimeo') !== -1) {
     videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("https://vimeo.com/", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/");
   }
}

console.log(videoUrl);

// Another option is to use regex
videoUrl = 'https://vimeo.com/';
if (/youtube/.test(videoUrl)) {
   videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
}
if (/vimeo/.test(videoUrl)) {
  videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("https://vimeo.com/", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/");
}
console.log(videoUrl);
```

Comment: what's wrong with `if (videoUrl.includes('youtube'))` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX `String.prottype.includes()` is not supported by all browsers

Comment: So? who really gives a damn about IE? it can be polyfilled anyway :p

Comment: @JaromandaX That's right but I will prefer using regex 
 `/youtube/.test(videoUrl)`

Comment: For those of you interested, [here is the official compatibility chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility) for `includes()`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Few days back I fixes bug due to  `includes()` for IE9 :P

Comment: by including a polyfill I hope, @ZohaibIjaz ... `String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) { return !!~this.indexOf(search, start); }`

Answer (score 1):

Just simply this:

```
if (videoUrl !== undefined && videoUrl !== null)
{
    if (videoUrl.indexOf('youtube') !== -1) {
        videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
    }
    else if (videoUrl.indexOf('vimeo') !== -1) {
        videoUrl = videoUrl.replace("https://vimeo.com/", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/")
    }
}
```

That removes the duplicate checks, and is easier to read. You cannot easily do it with a single `if`, unless you get into playing games with the `?:` operator.

In fact, let's play games!

```
videoUrl = (videoUrl !== undefined && videoUrl !== null) ?
              (videoUrl.indexOf('youtube') !== -1) ? 
                  videoUrl.replace("watch?v=", "embed/") :
                  (videoUrl.indexOf('vimeo') !== -1) ?
                      videoUrl.replace("https://vimeo.com/", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/") :
                  null :
               null;
```

Or something like that - now *that* is unreadable!

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as follows:

```
if (typeof videoUrl !== 'undefined' && videoUrl) {
  if (videoUrl.indexOf('youtube') !== -1) {
    //first case here
  } else if (videoUrl.indexOf('vimeo') !== -1){
    //second case here
  }
}
```

Comment: `typeof videoUrl !== 'undefined' &&` redundant